# Libcurl use cookie in c

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

i cant find tutorial about using cookies in c with curl. In php all simple and understandably. Somebody can explain me, how read/write and use cookie in c?

Comment: https://github.com/bagder/everything-curl/blob/master/libcurl-http-cookies.md

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial is [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) and example [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cookie_interface.html).